# How to change the values in two dimension array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am stuck with this two dimension array with Unity framework coding with c#. I am trying to create a Checker game with an Intelligent agent. So I trying to get all the pieces and passing to the Alpha Beta algorithm and get the maximum amount of Opponent side. But in order to do that I have to check each piece on my board. I am using 8by8 board on my game. So I used

Piece[,] pieces = new Pieces[8,8];

code in order to store the pieces. Now I want to change one piece and retrieve the pieces. 
I tried in several ways and experimented, But I could not found any to take this array and change one generic object and retrieve the list with the changes.

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

I written down here about what I experimented. Any suggestions about this matter or did I do something wrong?....

```
internal static void TryMoveInImaginaryWay(Piece[,] piece)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y =2;
    int x1 = 1;
    int y1 = 3;

    Moves move = new Moves();
    move.X = x;
    move.Y = y;
    move.X1 = x1;
    move.Y1 = y1;

    // Copping the pieces state
    Piece p = piece[x, y];

    //I am creating a list with those pieces
    List<Piece> temppiecelist = new List<Piece>();

    foreach (Piece pi in piece)
    {
        if (pi == p)
        {
            piece[x1, y1] = p;
            temppiecelist.Add(null);
        }
        else
        {
            temppiecelist.Add(pi);
        }
    }

    Piece[,] piek = temppiecelist; // can't convert it says Cannot Implicitly convert type "System.Collection.Generic.List<Piece>' to Piece[*,*]'"

    // I know i can't convert like this, but any ideas.
    //Piece[,] piek = new Piece[8, 8];
```

**I am asking about , Is there any way to change above Piece[,] array list values. And I want the same format as output.**

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed. Please do not use tags that are not directly related to your problem or your code. This potentially brings negative attention to your question since it annoys folks who follow the wrongly placed tags.

Comment: The same goes for the UnityScript tag, this is C#.

Comment: thanks for informing me. :)

Comment: Now that the formatting errors are resolved, I still don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: @TJWolschon - I gave the problem in the end. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a list at all?  We can't figure out what you are doing or why you would want to do it, so it is hard to advise you what the correct course of action is.

Comment: @EricLippert - I am creating a checker game and I want to change a piece values,and evaluate each pieces. Reference: Alpha Beta Pruning Algorithm. Thanks for giving me support.

Comment: An 8x8 array is a common and obvious way to represent a chequer board, but it is not the only way.  Consider for example instead using a directed graph where the vertices are the squares and the edges are the adjancencies. The rules are much more concisely represented on such a data structure than on an 8x8 grid.

Comment: @EricLippert - I agreed. Thanks, A lot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is make a copy of the board and then make a move on that board.

Why on you would get a List involved I cannot figure out; what led you to believe that a List was the right solution? I am interested to know; by learning why people come to bad conclusions about program writing, I can help them write better programs.

To make a mutated copy of the board, just *copy the board* and *mutate the copy*:

```
internal static void TryMoveInImaginaryWay(Piece[,] original)
{
    int x0 = 0;
    int y0 = 2;
    int x1 = 1;
    int y1 = 3;
    Piece[,] copy = (Piece[,])original.Clone();
    copy[x1,y1] = copy[x0,y0];
    copy[x0,y0] = null;
```

And you're done.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Yeh, I am just a beginning,  My code standards are not quite good. Thanks @Eric